# Boot Windows to recovery console, download file, run?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, recovery-console

Would the following be possible:

1. Boot into recovery console
2. Download an executable or installer (equivalent to wget?)
3. Load it into memory
4. Run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The recovery console is a minimal native WinNT environment and can not run normal Win32 ( even console ) programs.